# Django url path with question mark

Tags: python, django, rest, django-urls

I have got a question that I could not find an answer to. Is it possible in Django to create an URL path in urls.py that looks like the following?

```
path('article?date={some value here}/', article.site.urls)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is *not* part of the path, this is a sequence of key-value pairs.

In the view you can access this with `request.GET` which is a dictionary-like object.

You can thus define a path as:

```
path('article/', some_view)
```

and then in the view access the date with:

```
def some_view(request):
    date = request.GET.get('date')
    # …
```